# system policy prevents control of network connections

Tags: kde, networkmanager, authentication, polkit

When we log into a KDE seesion using X2Go client, the user is greeted with a dialog asking for a sudo password. I do not want the user to have a sudo password and I would like to prevent the dialog from appearing. The user should not be bothered with this.

The dialog title is: `Authentication Required PolicyKit1 KDE Agent`

The message is:

```
**System policy prevents control of network connections**  
An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. Authentication is required to perform this action.  
Password:

Action: Allow control of network connections  
ID: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control  
Vendor: NetworkManager  
polkit.subject-pid: 20440  
polkit.caller-pid: 708  

- process 708 is /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
- process 20440 is kded5 [kdeinit5]

pkaction version 0.116  (that's the policykit version)
```

The related policy is already defined so that authentication should not be requested / required:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control">
<_description>Allow control of network connections</_description>
<_message>System policy prevents control of network connections</_message>
<defaults>
  <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
</action>
```

Relevant log lines are:

```
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: "Password: "
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Request:  "Password: "
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: REQUEST
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Trying again

Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Action description has been found
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Message of action:  "System policy prevents control of network connections"
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Initiating authentication
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication callback for  0x55df1e7190a0
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: GSimpleAsyncResult: 
Aug 07 21:50:54 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Listener adapter polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication

Aug 07 21:50:43 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Authentication agent result: true
Aug 07 21:50:43 desktop polkitd[838]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:19 (system bus name :1.5274 [/usr/lib/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Aug 07 21:50:43 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Listener online
Aug 07 21:50:43 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: Adding new listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener
Aug 07 21:50:43 desktop polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[26611]: New PolkitAgentListener

Aug 07 21:50:42 desktop ksmserver[26587]: org.kde.kf5.ksmserver: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1.desktop" ("/usr/lib/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1")
```

What I have tried so far is creating this polkit rule:

`/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00-networkmanager.rules`

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system")
{
        polkit.log("NetworkManager.settings.modify.system: rule called");
    return polkit.Result.YES;
}
});

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control")
{
        polkit.log("NetworkManager.network-control: rule called");
    return polkit.Result.YES;
}
});
```

The rule is owned by root and has **644** permissions.

Comment: I really don't know about rule files, since the .pkla route works for me, but… that file looks script-ish—i'd be betting it needs execute permissions [I know, you could execute a bash script that doesn't have execute permission, too, but it would still be the first thing I'd try].

Answer (score 10):

Try with a `pkla` ([PolicyKit Local Authority](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html)) file:

```
$ sudo ls -la /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:08 .
drwx------ 7 root root 4096 Aug  1  2017 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  573 Dec 27 01:16 45-allow-colord.pkla
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  206 Dec 28 20:08 50-allow-network-manager.pkla

$ sudo cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-allow-network-manager.pkla
[Network Manager all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Thank you but that did not resolve it for me. I used the pkla file contents you show and the file has 640 permissions (and it owned by root). Did I miss any steps?

Comment: I would like to accept your answer. What else is required to get the solution to work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I doesn't work for you... It worked for me.

Comment: It also just worked for me, thank you @jsiwrk!

Comment: @MountainX you should create the file `50-allow-network-manager.pkla`

Comment: It only "just worked for you", if you restarted polkit: `systemctl restart polkit`. This looks a bit extreme. NetworkManager configuration really should do the `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control` configuration when you specify to allow all users to use an iinterface (otherwise, why even ask?), but isn't `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system` saying that all users should be **able** to use NetworkManager configuration? That _should_ require sudo access.

Answer (score 4):

**WARNING: This answer disables almost all of polkit's security protections.**

Try this:
Create a file named universal.pkla in the /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d folder with these contents:

```
    [Allow access to anything for remote users]
    Identity=unix-user:*
    Action=*
    ResultAny=yes
    ResultInactive=yes
    ResultActive=yes
```

Then restart polkit with "sudo systemctl restart polkit.service" or reboot.
I haven't seen any polkit authentication prompts since.

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 22 as a Guest through Microsoft Hyper-V.

Comment: What is the point of security, if you're just going to turn it all off?!

Answer (score 0):

I use debian 12 (KDE) with xrdp / vnc , having met the same problem today.

Although this is an old question, but none of the answers works for me.

I fact I did use the `pkla` file way to fix the color manager problem once. But I don't know why this just wouldn't work for me this time.

Here is how I fix this after reading `man polkit`:

Instead of using `pkla` file, I made a rule file to allow "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control" action when the user is in "sudo" group.

Just create this config below:

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-allow-network-manager.rules
---
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
   if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control" &&
       subject.isInGroup("sudo")) {
       return polkit.Result.YES;
   }
});
```

And reboot your system after that.

---

update 2023/12/26:

You need to install `polkitd-pkla` package to make pklocalauthority works on debian:

```
sudo apt install polkitd-pkla
```

So this pkla does the same thing:

```
[Allow Network Manager]
Identity=unix-group:sudo;
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```